# view only top 10 from my star ranking

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 5 star rating system at my side and i want to view top 3 best rated, I am using the below sql query:

```
SELECT Ranking, Total_value FROM <Table> ORDER BY Rating DESC LIMIT 3;
```

but it don't show the top 3, it shows the 3 with the highest number, if 10 people have voted for one thing, and 20 people have voted for another thing, the one with 20 votes have the highest number, but not necessary have the highest rating, so how do i divide the number of votes with the total ranking?? so it shows the 3 with the best ranking

Hope someone can help me? and understand my question :)

Comment: Do you know how many people have voted? If not you will be completely unable to make an average. Average is found by adding all numbers together and then dividing that with the amount of numbers used.

Comment: What does ranking and rating mean? I suppose that rating is one vote, but shouldn't the ranking be calculated with this query you are trying to find?

Comment: Please post your table definitions and sample data for each table

Comment: Editing your post and fixing grammar is not enough. We need to know what the "Ranking" column is. What is the "Rating" column? What column has the total number of ratings? Where's the number of votes?

Comment: yes i know how many people have voted, i have a collum called ID and One called Total_votes and ond called Total_value and if i divide Total_votes with Total_value i get the ranking. but how do i do that?.

Comment: And you didn't think it might be helpful to mention that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can divide `Total_value` with `Total_votes`:

```
SELECT 
    Ranking, 
    Total_votes, 
    Total_value, 
    (Total_value / Total_votes) as `Average`
FROM
    Votes
ORDER BY
    (Total_value / Total_votes) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: but i have one more quastion, when i use the code below, it will come on the screen like this: name: ( the bedst rated ) name: ( the second bedst rated) name: ( the third bedst rated ) and so on. but if i want it to be numbers instead of name, like this: 1. ( the bedst rated ) 2. ( the second bedst rated ) and so on.....

Comment: <?php
    $server = "";
 $brugernavn = "";
 $kode = "";
 $db = "";
 
 mysql_connect($server , $brugernavn , $kode) or die(mysql_error());
 
 mysql_select_db($db) or die(mysql_error());
 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT 
    id, 
    Total_votes, 
    Total_value, 
    (Total_value / Total_votes) as `Average`
FROM
    ratings
ORDER BY
    (total_value / total_votes) DESC
LIMIT 3" )or die(mysql_error());
 
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
 {
 
 echo "name: " . $info['id'] . "<br/>";
 
 
 }
 
    ?>

Comment: You can declare `$i = 1;` before your `while` and in the end of your `while` you can add `$i++;` and simply print `$i`.

Comment: Please also note that you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: sorry im am pretty new doing this, what am i missing in my code?         
    $i = 1;
    
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
 {
 $i++;
 echo "name" . $info['id'] . "<br/>";
 
 
 }
 
    ?>

Comment: @user3035776 `echo $i . '. ' . $info['id']`.

Comment: thank you for your help :), works now

Comment: sorry to bother u again, but i have a quastion more to my top 3, i want to show what the rating is, if it has gotten only 5 stars i want to show 5.0 in the right side at the page, for that i use the below kode, and it's works okay, buuut it's shows 5.0000, right beside my id, i want some spaces between the id, and only one zero, how do i get it to look like this:  1. (id)                  5.0

Comment: $i = 0;
 while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
 {
 $i++;
 echo $i . ". " . $info['Navn']. $info['Average']. "<br/>";

Comment: First convert it to a number, then use `number_format`: `number_format((float)$info['Average'], 1)` with `1` being the amount of decimals you want to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You have to created a column in database called average.And update the average each time people rates.Then use query
SELECT Ranking, Total_value FROM  ORDER BY average_value DESC LIMIT 3;